# RVM usage on multi user environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I have multiple users working on a rails app in my Ubuntu machine with user id(s) (say user1, user2 ...). Currently we are installing RVM per user and are installing Rails post gemset creation. The problem is for every new user on a machine the entire stack (RVM, Ruby, Rails) needs to be set for each account.

Is this the best strategy or does it make sense to install RVM at the system level (say as root) and share it among other users. If RVM is installed as root, will gemset creation / libraries be available under the respective home directories.

What would be the best way to manage multi users working on a Rails.

Comment: [RVM site](https://rvm.io) contains answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the RVM doc says it all: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/#explained

**Installation explained**

*There are three different ways to install and configure RVM.*

Single-User installations (recommended)

- For an isolated install within a user's $HOME

Multi-User installations

- For server administrators - For an installation usable by all users on the system - **Please note that Single-User supercedes Multi-User.** This also used to be called the System-Wide Install. **Using this type of installation without knowledge how umask works is a big security risk.**

Mixed mode installations

- For an installation usable by all users on the system - with isolated rubies/gemsets within a user's $HOME. Installation instructions are exactly the same as for Multi-User installations, the difference is in users environment.